# Can I embed go to my C/C++ project using dynamic linking?

Tags: c, go

Take python as example, a C/C++ program can load libpython.so dynamically and create a python VM, and then feed user scripts to the python VM.

Is their a way to use go like this? Namely, dynamically load it from the user's system environment.

We want to embed go to our project for scripting, but we don't want to package it to our final binary program.

Thanks.

Comment: For "scripting"? But Go isn't a scripting language.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for reminding, I am new to `go`.

Answer (score 2):

On some platforms like Linux you can build your Go code with `-buildmode=c-shared` to get a shared library which can then be linked into a program written in another language like C.

Some examples and documentation are here: https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go-cshared-examples

Note that this does not make Go a scripting language--you still need to build shared libraries from Go code.  However, you could conceivably build them while your application is running and load them using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.  This is the same as how you could compile C code by launching a C compiler from inside your application, then load it.